# c# How to format mifare1k card

Tags: c#, smartcard

i have codings to wirte and read datas on mifare1k card... i want to format all datas in the card...how to format or simply delete the datas on particular memory block...

write block...

```
   if (connectCard())
        {
            submitText(txtShow.Text,"5");
            Close();
        }
```

read block...

```
if (connectCard())
        {
            string a = verifyCard("5");
            txtShow.Text = a.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: what you want to format? textbox text?

Comment: i mean...i want to erase all data's which are saved in the card....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formatting a card is a process where the data is written following a specification. For example, you can format a Mifare card to NDEF format by writting specific keys and specific data nodes with informations like type, size, etc.

If you want to delete data stored, make it like a new card, you can write zeros on data blocks, and update the Keys to the default ones.

Remember that on Mifare 1k cards the sector 0 of the block 0 is read-only. And the sector 3 is the sector trailer, with KEY A, Acess Bits and KEY B.

I suggest you to read some files:

- [Adafruit simplified doc about Mifare Cards](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pn532-rfid-nfc/mifare)
- [NXP Reference](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf)

Comment: thank you.... really ur message is helpful for me... now i understand that we cant write datas on sector 0,3,7,11 ,,,,  unfortunately  i already write some datas on that 0,3,7,11,,,blocks... it makes i cant write any datas on any blocks... can u pls help ..how to recover my card as new one..